# Which is better option to avoid duplicate insertion: delete and insert or check and insert?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Just got one doubt while performing insert operation. I want to keep records to be unique. So while inserting record currently I am executing delete() function to delete same record if exists and then using insert() function. But just thought that if I check that record is exists and insert only if that record not found. So I can avoid delete() operation. So which is better option?

This is my code.

```
public function insertPostLike($postId = null, $userId = null) {

        //This is to avoid duplicate entry for same user.
        $this->_db->delete($this->_name, array(
                'post_id = ?' => $postId,
                'user_id = ?' => $userId));

        $result = '';

        $arrData = array(
            'post_id'     => $postId,
            'user_id'     => $userId,
            'liked_date'  => Zend_Date::now()->toString('yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss')
        );

        if (!is_null($postId)) {
            $result = $this->insert($arrData);
        }

        return $result;
 }
```

I am using zend framework.

Comment: you can try `unique key` features

Comment: I think the answer to this depends on where you need the integrity enforcement to reside.  If the logic needs to be independent of the code then using a UNIQUE constraint (if your DBMS supports that) on the table makes the most sense.  If you are keeping all of your integrity logic in the code layer then it is probably more efficient to use Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists rather than perform a DELETE for every query.

Comment: @ski4404 How to use Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists  against two columns? I mean that my validation must check record contains **post_id and user_id**..Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: @ski4404 Resolved issue by customizing Zend_Validate_Db_RecordExists select statement. Got clue from following link: [link](http://jeremycook.ca/2011/10/25/zend_form-and-validating-values-for-multiple-column-db-keys/)